# How to list top 10 school with active record - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have two models: `School` and `Review`.

The `School` model looks like this: `{ID, name, city, state}`

The `Review` model looks like this: `{ID, content, score, school_id}`

How do I list the top ten schools based on the score from the review model?

I thought maybe a method in the school-model, with something like this:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
 def top_schools
   @top_schools = School.limit(10)
   ...
 end
end
```

And then loop them in a `<li>` list:

```
<div>
 <ul>
   <% @top_schools.each do |school| %>
      <li>school.name</li>
   <%end>
 </ul>
</div>
```

But, I dont really know how to finish the `top_schools` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make an average of reviews of each school.

The SQL query if you are running with MySQL should be something like:

```
SELECT schools.* FROM schools 
JOIN reviews ON reviews.school_id=schools.id 
GROUP BY schools.id
ORDER BY AVG(reviews.score) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

**Translated in Rails:**

In your School model:

```
scope :by_score, :joins => :reviews, :group => "schools.id", :order => "AVG(reviews.score) DESC"
```

In your controller:

```
@top_schools = School.by_score.limit(10)
```

The choice not to include the limitation in scope, can be more flexible and allow the display of 5 or 15.

I have only tested MySQL request. I am not sure on my rails translation.

Comment: thats interesting, I tried it but it only return one result when I loop throw it.

Comment: I replaced SUM(reviews.score)/SUM(1) by AVG(reviews.score) to improve performences

Comment: Sorry it return only one value beacause I hade only one review. I workt great! Thanks mate!

Comment: Great! Happy to see it's helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I totally missed the reviews model in that answer.

```
School.all(:select => "schools.*, AVG(reviews.score) as avg_score", 
:joins => :reviews, 
:group => 'schools.id', 
:order => 'avg_score desc', 
:limit => 10)
```

But this will get slower as you add reviews.  I like the total_score answer.

Comment: where exactly should I put the scope part?

Comment: in school.rb towards the top.  I usually put scopes after associations (has_many, has_one, etc..) and before model validations.  scope :top_schools and def self.top_schools actually do exactly the same thing.  1 is just shorter than the other.

Comment: Alright! where in the controller should I put the @top_school= School.top_schools? index-method? What if I have this page in antoher controller, should I put it there

Comment: It should go in the controller action that matches the view you pasted above.  If thats index.html.erb then put it in the SchoolsController index action.  If you want the top 10 schools in another controller action you can put it there as well.  Any controller will be able to call School.top_schools.  (also the <% end> in the view above should be <% end %>)

Comment: I misread your original post! eek. reviews are in a separate model correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24153/discussion-between-blamattina-and-shumacupcake)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each school only has one review ( `has_one` and `belongs_to`), you'd want to order the reviews first and then find the corresponding school:

```
Review.order('score DESC').first(10).each do |r|
   School.find_by_id(r.school_id)
end
```

Comment: so, are you wanting to list the schools in order by "average review score" or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new field `total_score` to the schools table - set to 0 by default. And then add a callback in the Review model to calculate the total score for the school when a new review is added/updated to that school.

Then do this:
`School.order("total_score DESC").limit(10)`